# Kivy in Jypiter notebook: OSError: source code not available

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, kivy, kivy-language, oserror

Im̀ trying to create a code that uses kivy library to create a window that has a button as widget. To do that I used the following code copied from a online video so as far as I know it should work:
(Each running cell will be divided by some dots, as the first one runs with no problems but the second is where the error occures)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.interactive import InteractiveLauncher
from kivy.lang import Builder

#forzar a la app a no iniciar en pantalla completa
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set("graphics", "fullscreen", "0")

janela = None
glayout= None
...
class WindowApp(App):
    pass

window = WindowApp()
wi = InteractiveLauncher(janela)
wi.run()
```

#the error that appears on the console after running the second cell goes like this:

```
[WARNING] [Deprecated  ] Call to deprecated function __init__ in /home/alfred/anaconda3/envs/k39/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kivy/interactive.py line 308.Called from /tmp/ipykernel_5673/4179568724.py line 5 by <module>().
 Exception in thread Thread-5 (startApp):
 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/alfred/anaconda3/envs/k39/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
     self.run()
   File "/home/alfred/anaconda3/envs/k39/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 946, in run
     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
   File "/home/alfred/anaconda3/envs/k39/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kivy/interactive.py", line 319, in startApp
     app.run(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/home/alfred/anaconda3/envs/k39/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 954, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "/home/alfred/anaconda3/envs/k39/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 923, in _run_prepare
     self.load_kv(filename=self.kv_file)
   File "/home/alfred/anaconda3/envs/k39/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 676, in load_kv
     default_kv_directory = dirname(getfile(self.__class__))
   File "/home/alfred/anaconda3/envs/k39/lib/python3.10/inspect.py", line 785, in getfile
     raise OSError('source code not available')
 OSError: source code not available
```

```
kvcode= """
FloatLayout:
    Button:
        size_hint: .1, .1
        pos_hint: {"x":.3, "top": 1.}
        text: "A"

"""
glayout= Builder.load_string(kvcode)
janela.root_window.add_widget(glayout)
```

After running the last cell a black window that crashes appears. So far Im quite new to using the Kivy library so Im̀ quite lost about what counld have gonne wrong since I've seen this code run without problems online.

Comment: Jupyter notebooks don't play well with GUI libraries.

Comment: Seems you missed the method `build` (as you are using method `load_string` to define the `root`).